# Error when using drop menu to change database value

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax, menu

When i select a drop menu option to change a value in my database to the selected value it gives this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list changeGroup("email@email.com")
```

Basically what im trying to do is I have an app that stores contacts, in the ungrouped contacts section it has the drop menu and when u select a value from it it submits the values and uses the value to update the database. I use the:

```
action='javascript:changeGroup(".$contactDetails.")
```

to tell the update statement which contact to update.

my code:

```
<!--Include Database connections info-->
<?php include('config.php'); ?>

<!--Links to CSS file for formatting-->
<link href="Contacts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<!--Links to Javascript file for the for action to change the group of a contact-->
<script src="ajax.js" language="javascript"></script>

<?php

$contactDetails = $_GET['contactDetails'];

    $cdquery="SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `newEmail` = '$contactDetails'";
    $cdresult=mysql_query($cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from first table failed: ".mysql_error());

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cdresult)) 
  {

    echo "" . $row['newFname'] . " " . $row['newLname'] . "'s " . "Details:";
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Name:</th>";
    echo "<th>Email Address:</th>";
    echo "<th>Phone:</th>";
    echo "<th>Postal Address:</th>";
    echo "<th>Group:</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['newFname'] . " " . $row['newLname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['newEmail'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['newPhone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['newAddress'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['group'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    echo "<form action='javascript:changeGroup(".$contactDetails.")' method='get'> Add contact to 
    <select id='group' name='group' onchange='this.form.submit(value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)'>
    <option>Select a group...</option> 
    <option value='Family'>Family</option> 
    <option value='Friends'>Friends</option> 
    <option value='Colleagues'>Colleagues</option></select>
    group.</form>";

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

ajax function:

```
function changeGroup(str)
    {
    document.getElementById("content02").innerHTML="";
    if (str=="")
    {
    document.getElementById("content02").innerHTML="";
    return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("content02").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("content02").innerHTML = "";
    }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",'getChangeGroup.php?contactChange='+contactChange+'&group='+group,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = changeReload;
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
```

php:

```
<!--Include Database connections info-->
<?php include('config.php'); ?>

<!--Links to CSS file for formatting-->
<link href="Contacts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<?php

$contactChange = $_GET['contactChange'];
$group = $_GET['group'];

$cdquery="UPDATE `contacts` SET `group` = '$group' WHERE `newEmail` = '$contactChange'";
$cdresult=mysql_query($cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from first table failed: ".mysql_error());

mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what your code does, nor do I have the patience to completely replicate it on my end, but as it stands you are passing a variable to your function, instead of a string, on this line:

```
echo "<form action='javascript:changeGroup(".$contactDetails.")' method='get'> Add contact to
```

To fix that, you need to quote your string as an actual string:

```
echo "<form action='javascript:changeGroup(\'".$contactDetails."\')' method='get'> Add contact to
```

I would assume this is your main issue.  Without those quotes, javascript treats your echoed variable as a js variable, instead of a string.

**In regards to your db interaction...**

Also, you are using a deprecated.. and soon to be removed database interaction API.  I recommend PDO to replace it, it prevents injection attacks and won't be removed in the near future, [learn more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).

Comment: @Corey If this answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the outlined checkmark next to the answer.